# 1 sec delay lasts almost 2 sec

Tags: vba, excel, timedelay

I am writing a code to copy data from one spreadsheet to an other one in every second. I have tried Application.Wait and Sleep but they blocked both spreadsheets so I decided to use a do until loop. It works but 1 sec lasts almost 2 sec and I don't know why. So I left only the loop in the code but the test gave the same result (it took ca 95 sec). Any suggestion?  Here is the code:

```
    Sub Test()

    Dim Delay As Date

    cell = 1

    For i = 1 to 60

     Workbooks("Data").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & cell).Value = cell

     cell = cell +1
     Delay = Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01")

     Do Until Now() >= Delay

      Do Events

     Loop

    Next i

    End Sub
```

Comment: So you have loop inside which you do some processing then wait a second, could it be that your extra time is the processing? What happens if you turn off screen updating first then turn it back on at the end using `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`, does that speed it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is only an approximate delay because you really have no idea of what else is going through the message queue and being processed by the `DoEvents` command (one word btw). An alternative would be to call the procedure from within itself with the [Application.OnTime method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196165.aspx).

```
Sub timed_routine()
    Application.Interactive = False
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1) = 1
    Application.Interactive = True
    'Debug.Print Timer
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), "timed_routine"
End Sub
```

With the `Debug.Print Timer` command uncommented and active, this routine was cycling in about 1.015 seconds.

Comment: I really appreciate all the help you gave me. I used Application.OnTime and it works flawlessly. Thank you Jeeped. Thank you Dave.